# If $X\approx Y$ and $X$ is convex then $Y$ might not be convex

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ and $Y$ be subspaces of an euclidean space. If $X$ is homemorph to $Y$ that is  $X\approx Y$ ($f$,$f^{-1}$ continuous and $f$ bijective) and $X$ convex. Prove that $Y$ is not necessary convex.

I found a counterexample in this link [Are homeomorphisms convex-preserving?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099787/are-homeomorphisms-convex-preserving/2099797#2099797)

> $\varphi:(x,y)\mapsto (x,y^3)$. It is a homeomorphism ($\varphi^{-1}:(x,y)\mapsto (x,\sqrt[3]{y}$) and the image of the first diagonal is $y=x^3$ which is not convex.

I do not see clear what is $Y$ in this case.

Also what it means with  "the image of the first diagonal is $y=x^3$" ?

where does it come from?

If someone could explain please, thank you.

Comment: There are simpler counterexamples.  Let $X$ be an interval and let $Y$ be an "L".

Comment: What does $\approx$ stand for here?

Comment: An homeomorphis between X and Y

Comment: What is a "L" ?

Comment: @vino For instance, the set $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, (x=0\land 0\le y\le 1)\lor(y=0\land0\le x\le 1\}$.

Comment: Note that even on an intuitive level, convexity is a geometric (and *extrinsic* at that) property rather than topological, so the claim should immediately sound suspect to you.

Comment: Also, the answer in your link is answering a different question than the one you have in your title.  Your title asks if homeomorphic spaces must both be convex if one of them is.  The answer in the linked question shows that homeomorphims themselves may not preserve convexity.  (The linked answer also doesn't answer the original question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the sake of a proof without words:

[image]